# Comparing values in environments in angular - condition will always return true

Tags: angular, typescript

we have a hybrid app that bootstraps differently for dev/preview environments (run on localhost) and qa/stg(using onDeviceReady() for cordova)

so, we have this in environment.dev.ts

```
export const environment {
   envName: 'DEV'
}
```

and this in our environment.preview.ts

```
export const environment {
   envName: 'PREVIEW'
}
```

there is a point in main.ts where we need to make the comparison b/w environments to make a choice of bootstraping the app

so we have this code

```
if(environment.envName === 'DEV' || environment.envName === 'PREVIEW') {
   // do something
}
```

However, when doing this, i am facing this error

**The condition will always return true as there is no overlap between the types '"DEV"' and '"PREVIEW"' have no overlap**

I am understanding the types are considered as DEV/PREVIEW ?

Any suggestions to get this fixed?

Comment: You have used `||` which is equivalent to `or`, so either way it will turn to true.

Comment: You can use two `if` to check for which environment is available and do what is required i.e. separate the two statements into a different `if`.

Comment: Is it a warning or an error? Is it from typescript compiler or your IDE? And can you show your `environment.ts` file?

Comment: Also, it is your real code? You've got a typo (missing the `=`), so maybe your code above does not reflect the problem

Comment: @David this is an error from TS compiler.

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBasePath: 'http://localhost:6200/bin/services',
  serverBasePath: 'http://localhost:6200',
  isMock: false,
  appVersion: '5.0.3',
  envName: 'DEV'
};

Comment: That's weird. Can you try modifying your env files to do an explicit cast? `envName: 'DEV'  as string` and  `envName: 'PREVIEW' as string`?

Comment: tried that. wouldnt help . infact, tried adding a model type envName: 'DEV' | 'PREVIEW as well. Tried both string and this type. no effect